# Await Future from Executor: Future can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, future, python-asyncio

I wanted to use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) from a [python coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html), to delegate some blocking network calls to a separate thread. However, running the following code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import asyncio

def work():
  # do some blocking io
  pass

async def main():
  executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
  await executor.submit(work)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

causes error:

```
TypeError: object Future can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Aren't `Future` objects *awaitable*? Why does it say they aren't?

How can I `await` a `Future` object returned by `executor.submit`?

*Python 3.5.0*

**EDIT**

Using `executor.submit` is not my decision. This is used internally by several libraries, like [`requests-futures`](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures). I am searching for a way to interop with those modules from coroutines.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should use [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import asyncio

def work():
  # do some blocking io
  pass

async def main(loop):
  executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
  await loop.run_in_executor(executor, work)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
loop.close()
```

**EDIT**

[`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object are different from [`asyncio.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future). The `asyncio.Future` is intended to be used with event loops and is *awaitable*, while the former isn't. `loop.run_in_executor` provides the necessary interoperability between the two.

**EDIT #2**

> Using executor.submit is not my decision. This is used internally by several libraries, like requests-futures. I am searching for a way to interop with those modules from coroutines.

**EDIT #3**

Since python 3.5 ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html)), you can use `asyncio.wrap_future(future, *, loop=None)` to convert a `concurrent.futures.Future` to a `asyncio.Future`.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. This certainly works. However I am more interested in *why* rather than *how*. Also, I use the futures-requests library, which uses submit internally.

Comment: The simple *why* is `concurrent.futures.Future` are not awaitable. You are thinking of `asyncio.Future`.

Comment: Okay, so we have different types called Future. Is there a conversion between those types?

Comment: [`asyncio.wrap_future`](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/asyncio/futures.py#L445) might be what you are looking for. Although I'm not sure if it's *public* or listed anywhere in the docs.

Comment: asyncio.wrap future [is documented there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.wrap_future) (but the doc doesn't say anything @JashandeepSohi hasn't said.)

Comment: This is extremely helpful, and I'm glad to have found this explanation. But I would argue that having two different `Future` classes in Python's standard library is a bad design choice.